# UI of Kdenlive on Windows 10 has gone haywire

Tags: windows-10, kdenlive

I've been using Kdenlive for video editing on Windows 10 for a few weeks.  It worked fine until a couple of days ago.  Now, whenever I open it the normal UI appears for about a second, to be replaced by an almost blank window.

Here's what it looks like in that first second or so:

[image]

And here's what it looks like after that:

[image]

Right-clicking near the top of the window I can see the context menu for selecting which panes to view:

[image]

And right-clicking elsewhere in the window displays different context menus.  So it seems as if the application is working, just not rendering the window correctly.

I've tried uninstalling Kdenlive then reinstalling it but that made no difference.  Originally I had v20.04 installed but the new version is v20.08.  The Windows 10 version is 1909 (build 18363.1139).

Has anyone any idea what might be causing this?  Does Kdenlive rely on any other background application that might have got corrupted?

I don't know if it's relevant but I was using the application on a docked laptop on a 24 inch 1920 x 1200 monitor.  I then moved it to another dock with a 27 inch 1920 x 1080 monitor, without shutting it down.  I can't remember if I closed Kdenlive down or left it running in the background when I moved to the new dock.  It was after a restart, back on the original dock with the 24 inch monitor, that I first noticed this problem.  I've tried viewing it on a 1920 x 1080 monitor again but that made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as soon as I posted the question I stumbled across the answer in the following note about Kdenlive issues when running on Windows: https://userbase.kde.org/Kdenlive/Manual/Windows_Issues#Intel_graphic_card_driver

It says:

> Press Win + R (Windows key and R key simultaneously) and type **appdata**.
> Go to `local` and within it open `kdenliverc` with an editor. Search for
> `[misc]` and delete `[misc]` and the following entry. Example:
>
> `[misc]` 
> `opengl_backend=15`
>
> Save and close `kdenliverc`. Restart Kdenlive.

The **kdenliverc** file is in the root of **AppData\Local\** (don't get distracted by the AppData\Local\kdenlive\ sub-folder).  Removing the `[misc]` section and the line beneath it from the kdenliverc file  did the trick.